# MSTest on VisualStudio.com behaving differently than local MSTest

Tags: tfs, json.net, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I have an ASP.NET Web API project and a Unit Test project to test the ApiControllers in the Web API project.  Each TestMethod instantiates the ApiController it is going to test as follows:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {
        MyApiController controller = new MyApiController();
        controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
        // Other configuration steps

        IEnumerable<MyObjects> myObjects = controller.Get();
        // Assertions
    }
}
```

This runs fine if I build locally and run the tests from Test Explorer.  However when I queue a new build in my TFS instance on VisualStudio.com, all of my unit tests fail with the following exception thrown from the HttpConfiguration ctor:

> MyTestMethod threw exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not
>   found: 'Void
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.set_IgnoreSerializableAttribute(Boolean)'.

Here's the callstack:

```
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonContractResolver..ctor(MediaTypeFormatter formatter)
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter..ctor()
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatterCollection.CreateDefaultFormatters()
at System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.DefaultFormatters()
at System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration..ctor(HttpRouteCollection routes)
at System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration..ctor() 
at MyTestClass.MyTestMethod()
```

All of my dependencies outside of standard .NET 4.5 dlls are in nuget packages which are checked into source control to be used by TeamBuild.  This is the only way (that I know of) to manage dependencies when using VisualStudio.com's build server.

Because TeamBuild is running in the cloud and not on a machine I own, I have very few tools to diagnose this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> All of my dependencies outside of standard .NET 4.5 dlls are in nuget
>   packages which are checked into source control to be used by
>   TeamBuild.

Did you configure the hosted build controller to point to that custom assemblies, see the following images, if yes and you still have the same error try to reproduce the case on a local build server.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this didn't fix my problem.  I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you try to reproduce the case in a separate local build server?

Comment: No. I don't have a local build server setup.  If I can't get this figured out then setting one up will have to be my next step I suppose.